# Getting NaN error in Android for Global Float

Tags: android, floating-point, global-variables, nan

I am new to android. I am developing an CGPA App for my college. though many apps are available, I just wanted to do one on my own.
Let me come to the Question..
I want to get all the GPA values to my Main_Activity.java so that i can calculate my CGPA. I used the concept of Global Variables using Application in android. But i get my output as NaN. Though I referred many articles, I cant clear that error. As I need to submit the app to my college I am in need of help..

First i would like to show you my global class..
    package com.example.cgpa;

```
import android.app.Application;

public class global extends Application{
  private Float f[]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
  private Float f1[]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
  public Float getfloat(int a){
    return f[a];
  }
  public void setfloat(Float a,int b){
    this.f[b]=a;
  }
  public Float getfloat1(int a){
    return f1[a];
  }
  public void setfloat1(Float a,int b){
    this.f1[b]=a;
  }
}
```

This is the place I have used the Global variables in mainactivity.java

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final global x=((global)getApplicationContext());
    Float t=0.0f,c=0.0f;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
      t+=x.getfloat(i);
      c+=x.getfloat1(i);
    }
    final Float g=t/c;
    txt.setText("Your CGPA is "+g.toString());
  }
});
```

Also this is the place I have set the values in *gpa1.java* and like the same way I have used this in other classes.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  Float[] n={4.0f,4.0f,3.0f,3.0f,3.0f,4.0f,2.0f,2.0f,1.0f};
  Float t=0.0f;
  Float c=0.0f;
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    c+=n[i];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    if(s[i]=="S")
        n[i]*=10;
    else if(s[i]=="A")
        n[i]*=9;
    else if(s[i]=="B")
        n[i]*=8;
    else if(s[i]=="C")
        n[i]*=7;
    else if(s[i]=="D")
        n[i]*=6;
    else if(s[i]=="E")
        n[i]*=5;
    else 
        n[i]*=0;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    t+=n[i];
  }     
  Float g=t/c;
  final global x=((global)getApplicationContext());
  x.setfloat(t, 0);
  x.setfloat1(c, 0);
  TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
  txt.setText("Your GPA is "+g.toString());}
});
```

You may also tell me how to get values from other classes as I already used intent and image buttons to move from main activity to other activities.

Comment: What tests have you done to find out where the NaN is appearing? For example, if it shows up in one of your arrays, you could put println calls in the setFloat or setFloat1 method.

Comment: Your **if**s are all **wrong**. You can't compare strings like that: you must use `equals`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends for your kind advice... I have found what's wrong. it is very silly.. (0/any number)=NaN.. I have just cleared the error using isNaN() method..
Thank you..